# Getting idea of how search filtering in React.js works

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I've started learning yesterday, and I am trying to use the pokemon API (https://pokeapi.co/) to make a simple web app where the user can search pokemons by name and filter by type.

For the searching, my idea is to filter the array of pokemon data as the user types in a query in a search box. What I don't understand is, the lifecycle of react.

It seems like I have to update the filtered-array immediately after I type something into my search box. How does this have to do with the life cycle of react component? In other words, which part of the lifecycle does this updating has to be in?

I am not asking for a code, but I would like to get some sense of how to begin this programming.

Thanks

Comment: You can find the tutorial on building search filter here https://youtu.be/RM_nXOyHwN0

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to understand is the state lifecycle for components - once you have a really good understanding of how that works then you'll see it's perfect for what you're trying to achieve.
Every time you modify a component state (say for example each time a character is entered into an input field for a pokemon that's being searched for,) React will call that components render(){} method. The newly modified state object will be available to any functions (in your case something like a filter function) or methods etc inside of the render function, and that concept will allow you to return JSX components based on whatever functions are operating with those state objects as parameters.

So basically I imagine something like this:
1. If there is no string for the filter in the state, load all the pokemon, else filter the list of pokemon with the string, and return the filtered list.
2. When something is typed into an input field, update the filter in the state with that value.
3. The render method is called, and the cycle would repeat.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still not 100% clear, but I think I am getting the sense. So, when I try to retrieve the list of pokemons from the API, do I actually have to loop through the API and put them into an array, or do we have to request the API for the changed data every time our keyword in the search box changes?

Comment: Another part of the react lifecycle, and the one I use the most for pulling data from an external source, is the componentWillMount(){} function.
It will be the first thing called before a component officially mounts, and will let you set states within it.
This way, you can pull whatever you need to from the API and store it in the state object as well.
I think it's generally a good idea to limit calls to external sources so if you make the api call once, store it in the state as an array, and then reference back to it whenever you need to you'll be in good shape.

Comment: So, does this sound a valid approach to you? : 1) Get data from API inside the componentWillMount(), 2) Create an array that stores the information of all pokemons in it, 3) render this data in the render() with some sort and filtering options given the data. Still not really clear.